# java -version is different from java_home

Tags: java, maven, path

I have set `JAVA_HOME` in system varaiable poiniting to jdk 1.7 and have restarted the system. But if i check java -version it shows

```
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

Where as in echo `%java_home%` it shows as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre.`

I have tried by placing `JAVA_HOME` on top of %SystemRoot%\system32 in PATH variable and checked, even it didnt help.

Could anyone help me on this.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: what is your %PATH% variable?

Comment: Check your `PATH` environment variable and remove entry for Java bin directory (or adjust these two to point whichever version you want).

Comment: Add the 1.8 jdk to the Environment variable?

Comment: The installation program of oracle jdk for windows has may be installed a control panel. These options overrides everything.